# How to set compatability off in ie8 using code

Tags: html, cross-browser, meta-tags, meta, ie8-compatibility-mode

How do i change the browser mode using code
I have tried 
But this only changes the document type. By default my page goes to ie8 compat view. I want it to render in ie8. The alignment is correct only in ie8 view.

Answer (score 0):

Your web development is done in a standard (W3C), so it only works in internet explorer 8 (obsolete). Use ie8 is not the same as using the compatibility view for ie8, the differences are very large, the engines are different and therefore the final views are also different.

Do not waste time developing for older browsers, use standards, learn from w3c.